# To what alignment belong psychic powers of telepathy, telekinesis and divination?

Tags: powers, alignment, black-crusade

When purchasing psychic powers from the schools of telepathy, telekinesis and divination, to what alignment are the advancements to be considered?

I am considering they are either unaligned or special in a way that they are not considered towards any advancement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As advancement, they are unaligned but it is not clearly written.**

In *Black Crusade - Core Rulebook*, Chapter 6: Psychic Power, page 212:

> Aligned Powers
>
> Certain powers, Nurgle, Slaanesh, and Tzeentch Powers, are
>   Aligned with that god. This has several effects.
>   First, taking one of these powers counts as an Advancement
>   that furthers a Heretic’s alignment with that God. Someone
>   Aligned to Nurgle taking Nurgle’s Rot increases his Alignment to
>   Nurgle by 1.

So we see that only the power aligned with a paticular god increase the Alignment.

And the schools of telepathy, telekinesis and divination are **special** in way  that they are not only used by Chaos agent, but also by Imperial agent. For this I can refer you to the other books from the WH40KRPG.